# [File Export]No such file or directory

Tags: android, file-io

I want to export a file to SDCARD, i have however this log message:

```
04-11 18:34:22.383: DEBUG/Carburant(5734): /mnt/sdcard/Carburant/alaa.peugeot.settings.dat (Is a directory)
```

I want to have `alaa.peugeot.settings.dat` not as a directory, but as a file.
Here is my code:

```
try{
            final SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    String fileName = context.getResources().getString(R.string.fileName);
    String fileDir = "" + preferences.getString("login", "") + "."+ preferences.getString("marque", "") + ".";

            File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/Carburant");
            dir.mkdirs();
            File file = new File(dir, fileDir+fileName);
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            File f1 = new File(context.getFilesDir(), fileDir+fileName);
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(f1);
```

What going on with the code?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you add "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" to your manifest?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing here. Why are you opening an input stream from scratch right after you write the file out? Also, how do you know the file is a directory and not a file?

Comment: @James: i added a Log.d in the FileNotFoundException, it indicates the above error .

Comment: @MByD @James: how to wipe all data in the emulator? /data/ /system /sdcard ? perhaps it'll solve the problem :\ .

Comment: @Androniennn - I think a simpler approach will be to check if the directory already exists before calling `mkdirs`